# Website displays differently in https from http. How to fix that

Tags: http, ssl, https

Sorry for this stupid question but

Can someone suggest why the following website is displaying differently in http and https? Here are the two links

https://www.sportengland.org/careers/jobs-at-sport-england/

http://www.sportengland.org/careers/jobs-at-sport-england/

the content is not displaying properly in http website is iFrame content.

Comment: Maybe it is due to mixed content?
http://www.w3.org/TR/mixed-content/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the HTTP or HTTPS protocol will not effect the format of the page.

It might be because they have hosted the site in two hosting one with SSL (HTTPS) and another with non SSL (HTTP).

And there could be chance that they updated one application and not done the same changes in another.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually its hosted in one environment.
To explain a bit more the script references https. if I view in http and look at firebugs i get this error (see new comment)
I am assuming this is something to do with loading https content (in iFrame) while being http session.

Comment: Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at https://portals.test.com/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=gFdhKfz4HOG1zwdPrX1gphItI9YNlBQ7n-Bs0Y57W_nrfccpsRp0PNBeV3hhAhGD4c9jvDUnOwGENSUfrFfoNIf-o7Yqjdf26V5okwt1USB3suIG6z9vXCm1wF08Urn1H_qQEhyDoexbGe-4h-uw6Q2Ozg5aPr0mLxaR1mAC7nF1L8_HSUpiroJTt0J7boSt0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22notificationhub%22%7D%5D&tid=10.

https://portals.test.com/_resx/js/jquery.signalR-1.0.1.min.js